# Resetting React Form values after validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-framework

have that problem with resetting the values of the input fields in the form. and wanted to ask if somebody knows a better and way to do that instead of just making 'useState' for every field...

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        emailjs.sendForm('sample_id', 'someother_id', formRef.current, 'user_is')
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });

        setMessage(true);
        setEmail("");
        setName("");
        setSubject("");
        setTextarea("");
    };

    return (
        <div className="contact" id="contact">
            <div className="left">
                <img src="" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                <h2>Kontakt</h2>
                <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Name" name="user_name" value={name} />
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email" placeholder="Email" name="user_email" value={email} />
                    <label>Betreff</label>
                    <input onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="user_subject" value={subject} />
                    <label>Nachricht</label>
                    <textarea onChange={(e) => setTextarea(e.target.value)} placeholder="Message" name="message" value={textarea} />
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    {message && <span>Thanks we will respond ASAP.</span>}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a state for every field, you can have one state (an object) that responsible for all fields and then implement [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to handle the state updates.

Comment: [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useResetRecoilState) has a reset feature for state, too

Comment: @jsejcksn using a library just for resetting the state is a bit overkill no?

Comment: @MartinZ Is it overkill to use React just to implement a form? We have no idea how complicated his app is.

Comment: @jsejcksn considering the title includes "React form" I suspect hes already using React anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single state for all the form values (kinda like we did before functional components)

```
// this could be outside your component
const initialState = { email: "", name: "", subject: "", textArea: ""};
// declaring your state
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState(initialState);
```

and then

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    emailjs.sendForm('sample_id', 'someother_id', formRef.current, 'user_is')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });

    setMessage(true);
    setFormState(initialState)
};
```

You also would have to rewrite your input handlers. Like that :

```
<input onChange={(e) => setFormState({...formState, name: e.target.value})} type="text" placeholder="Name" name="user_name" value={name} />
```

Comment: You should use the prevState callback in setState-function when muting the state based on the previous state. I.E: 
`setFormState((prevFormState) => ({...prevFormState, name: e.target.value})`

Comment: Thanks @MartinZ and user17578550 for giving me this useful examples, i appreciate it!!